# fread into array of structs segmentation fault

Tags: c, file, struct, fread, calloc

I've been working on this code for awhile now and I've run into a seg fault that I can't seem to debug. Here's the relevant code:

```
typedef struct Halo* Halo;  
struct Halo  
{  
    float x, y, z;  
    float vx, vy, vz;  
    int n200a;  
    float m200a;  
    float r200a;  
    int n200c;  
    float m200c;  
    float r200c;  
    int n500a;  
    float m500a;  
    float r500a;  
    int n500c;  
    float m500c;  
    float r500c;  
};
```

Global variable:

Halo *halo_catalog;

The function that fails:

```
int loadHaloCatalog(char *filename)  
{  
    FILE *catalog_file;  
    long long halo_num;

    catalog_file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (catalog_file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open halo catalog: %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }
    if (fread(&halo_num, sizeof(long long), 1, catalog_file) < 0) {  
        printf("Could not read number of halos\n");  
        return -1;  
    }  
    halo_catalog = (Halo *)calloc(halo_num, sizeof(struct Halo));  
    if (fread(halo_catalog, sizeof(struct Halo), halo_num, catalog_file) < 0) {  
        printf("Could not read that number of halos\n");  
        return -1;  
    }  
    printf("%f\n", halo_catalog[10000]->x);  
    printf("done\n");  
    fclose(catalog_file);  
    return (int)halo_num;  
}
```

It fails on the "printf("%f\n", halo_catalog[10000]->x);" line, or any other access to the memory that is allocated after the fread call. I know that I am passing in a valid file, as it can read halo_num correctly. It also collects the correct about the Halo objects from the fread call, as when I call fread and check the return it returns halo_num.

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `typedef struct Halo* Halo;` to `typedef struct Halo Halo;`; and `halo_catalog[10000]->x` to `halo_catalog[10000].x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef struct Halo* Halo;
```

That's a terrible idea, and probably the cause of your problems.

You have a global variable

```
Halo *halo_catalog;
```

so a `struct Halo**`. But in

```
halo_catalog = (Halo *)calloc(halo_num, sizeof(struct Halo));  
if (fread(halo_catalog, sizeof(struct Halo), halo_num, catalog_file) < 0) {
```

you use it as if it were a `struct Halo*`.

Then you index

```
printf("%f\n", halo_catalog[10000]->x);
```

at a distance of `10000 * sizeof(struct Halo*)` bytes from where `halo_catalog` points, and interpret the bytes at that location - which are part of the values of some `float`s or `int`s read in, not pointers - and try to access the `x` component of whatever arbitrary location was the result of that misinterpretation.

You should

```
typedef struct Halo Halo;
```

and use `halo_catalog[10000].x` to fix that issue.

Another issue is that `fread` returns the number of items it has successfully read, if that is smaller than the requested number, it can still be a positive number.

Capture the return value of `fread`, and use that to determine whether the reading was completely successful. Also, be sure that 10000 is a valid index before trying to print `halo_catalog[10000].x`.

Answer (score 2):

Does that actually compile?

The issue is that halo_catalog is a pointer to an array, not an array of pointers. You should be using `printf("%f\n", halo_catalog[10000].x);`

I'm assuming the 10000 is just for testing purposes? Because there's nothing I saw that guarantees there are 10000 records in the halo_catalog.

Comment: It does compile. There are approximately 60k Halos so that isn't an issue.

Comment: Also, I think my issue stems from a misunderstanding of the typedef.

Comment: I changed my definition to Halo halo_catalog instead of Halo*.
Then I made your code changes and it worked.
So when I do the typdef, it changes Halo* to represent both a pointer to a Halo and a pointer to an array of Halo objects?

Comment: Yeah... using a pointer in a typedef is rarely a good idea. I actually missed that in my original reply. As a result, halo_catalog was a pointer to a pointer to an array of Halo... thus it did compile, but didn't work. You were allocating an array of Halo (which is what I saw in my original reply). The compiler probably should have whined about you assigning a Halo* to a Halo** in your calloc call... dunno if you got a warning there or not. Anyway, the other answer is the better one given that I missed the pointer in the typedef.